# Why names such as Hastings-on-Hudson?

Tags: etymology, history, names

This question is either about etymology or language generally, as names have this feature in other languages too, but I'm just curious how the practice of naming towns in proximity to bodies of water with a built-in reference to those bodies of water came about. Obviously it's not strange to me that a town on the Hudson would be called "-on-Hudson" etc., but what "determined" or at least influenced whether a town's name ended up having a reference to a body of water as well? It's not Chicago-on-Michigan or Philadelphia-on-Delaware, so why so many "-on-Hudson" towns?

Comment: In the specific example you made, the village could have been called Hastings-on-Hudson to avoid confusion with Hastings, a town in the same state but a different county, or with other towns in different states.

Comment: It's not unique to naming of municipalities in English; while most non-Germans know of one city called "Frankfurt", that city is really "Frankfurt am Main", as contrasted with the lesser-known "Frankfurt an der Oder"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far as I'm aware, the normal reason for adding **-on-[river]** is the obvious one - to avoid confusion with another place of the same name which *isn't* on that particular river.

But I suppose sometimes **-by/-on-sea**, **-in-the-moor**, **-in-the-dale**, etc., might be used to publicise the local geography of a resort to encourage tourists, etc. It could well be that in the past, when people's water came from the river rather than the tap, naming a nearby river might also be helpful in attracting visitors/settlers.

Being British, I don't know *any* US place-names **xxxx-on-Hudson**, but I could believe that mentioning that mighty river adds a touch of [kudos](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kudos) to some otherwise unremarkable places.

It's worth pointing out that by and large the name of a place is what the locals (and more specifically, their administrative bodies) choose to call it. Each town may have its own reasons for choosing their particular form of name, and it doesn't have to conform to any particular rules. Even granting that there might be any such rules in the first place.

Comment: Another reason for these names is the prestige of the name "Hudson". Having a view of the Hudson River, at least in New York City, means the property is expensive. It's not hard to make the jump to this logic being applied to Croton on Hudson, Hastings on Hudson, et cetera--all towns north of the city on the river.

Comment: @Neil Fein: Umm. I did mention that being on the *mighty* Hudson might add kudos. The same could apply to **Kingston-Upon-Thames** near/in London.

Comment: Huh, didn't see that when I read the answer before, I obviously missed it. I wonder if towns choose these names in an attempt to push up property values? (Nice answer, by the way.)

Comment: @Neil Fein: I wonder if there are any places in Egypt called *Somewhere-on-Nile* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I always assumed that was to distinguish it from [Kingston upon Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingston_upon_Hull)? Not that anyone calls it anything other than just "Hull", in practice... (I looked for places in Egypt called "-on-Nile", but searching for على النيل online just returns a lot of hotels with a river view...)

Comment: @psmears: I only said it *could* be a factor. First line of my Answer says I think disambiguation is the primary reason. If 'kudos' is ever relevant, it might applies more to *Henley-on-Thames*. Which some folk might not otherwise realise was on our grandest watercourse, even if they were in no danger of confusing it with the equally-salubrious *Henley-in-Arden*. Though I suppose you'd have to be a bit out of touch not to know about the Southern Henley's connection with boating.

Comment: Disambiguation was the primary reason for Washington-on-the-Brazos in Texas (as opposed to Washington-on-the-Potomac).

Comment: @user744: I think we can be pretty certain disambiguation is the primary reason *on average*. The real issue to be explored is what if any other reasons might (sometimes) come into play, and how much influence they might have. It's not obvious to me that [Tanworth-in-Arden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanworth-in-Arden), for example, needs disambiguating from any other Tanworth (there may well not even be another one).

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted this answer in the interest of closure and in the absence of a better one, though if anyone has some sort of documented history of this sort of naming scheme, I'd still be delighted to see it.

Comment: @Philip: Well, so far as I can see there's only one place properly called **Croton** in America. Although it's got [less than 8000 inhabitants](http://village.croton-on-hudson.ny.us/Public_Documents/CrotonHudsonNY_WebDocs/CrotonHistory), *Croton-on-Hudson* is the only one I find anywhere, except Wikipedia says [Hartford, Ohio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croton,_Ohio) is "also called Croton". But that's only got 405 inhabitants anyway, so the one on the Hudson is hardly likely to be mistaken for it. Your hopes for a "better" answer are probably forlorn.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I should have mentioned, this naming scheme is not restricted to English, as evidenced by such names as Évian-les-Bains and neighboring towns on Lac Léman (many -les-Bains and -sur-Léman); on which note, the Wiki article on [Évian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89vian-les-Bains#The_Golden_Age_of_the_Belle_epoque_and_the_Roaring_Twenties) further supports your publicity / "name-as-advertisement" theory.

Answer (score 3):

*One answer:* It's easier to pronounce than "Weckquaesgeek"!

*Better answer:* There are many ways in which place names reflect the local geography, and that often includes references to bodies of water. Think of all the place names that include words like "brook," "river," "bay," "beach," "creek," "lake," "pool," "spring," and so on.

One obviously important factor in the name of a place is the origin of the people who settled that place. The earliest Europeans to explore and settle eastern New York were the Dutch, and many place names there end in "kill" (Catskill, Freshkills, Beaver Kill, Fishkill, West Kill...) which is apparently Dutch for stream or river. The ...-on-Hudson nomenclature sounds English, like Berwick-upon-Tweed or Stratford-upon-Avon, and indeed Hastings-on-Hudson was [earlier called Hastings-upon-Hudson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hastings-on-Hudson,_New_York).

I don't think there's any particular characteristic that determines whether a village is named ...-on-Hudson, although it would seem necessary that the place actually be located along the Hudson river. It's just one of many ways that places use their name to distinguish themselves. Other places near Hastings-on-Hudson are Dobbs Ferry and Sleepy Hollow, so the river isn't the only feature that made its way into local names.

Answer (score 0):

In Ontario it's common to see place names that end in Station, and for there to be something nearby that is the same name without Station. (An example near me is [Myrtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrtle,_Ontario) and [Myrtle Station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myrtle_Station,_Ontario), about a kilometre apart. Myrtle presumably came first and got its name however it did, and Myrtle Station would be the settlement at the train tracks, presumably after a stop was added.)

In the same way, there may have been a just plain Hastings - on a train line, a trail, a road or whatnot - and a companion town on the river where boats could stop. In that case, Hastings-on-Hudson seems like a fine way to distinguish the two. Whether it's true in that case or not I can't say, but it's an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In 1989, the town meeting of Manchester, Massachusetts voted 97–95 in favor of changing its legal name to Manchester-by-the-Sea in order to disambiguate it from other U.S. Manchesters, most notably Manchester, New Hampshire, which is only an hour drive away.

> There are a couple of dozen Manchester scattered throughout this country and elsewhere; this Town, however, is the only one which could add “by-the-Sea” to its legal title[...] being the only Manchester anywhere in the universe with the fortunate happenstance of being in close proximity to the sea.
>
> On numerous occasions, while I was employed at the police station [in Manchester, Mass.] nights, people traveling to [New Hampshire] lost their way and wound up in the [police] station looking for Nashua or Rochester[.]
>
> — ["Town Meeting." *The Manchester Cricket*. May 12, 1989. p12. (Archived)](http://manchestercricket.advantage-preservation.com/viewer/?i=f&by=1989&bdd=1980&d=01011989-12311989&m=between&ord=k1&fn=manchester_cricket_usa_massachusetts_manchester_19890512_english_12&df=1&dt=10&cid=2816)

Comment: We used to call it "Appalachia-by-the-Sea" ;-)